# An example of an Interval Translation Map

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider the circle $\mathbb{T}^1:=\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$. We represent it as a union of disjoint subsegments $M_j=[t_j,t_{j+1})$, $j=0,\cdots, n$ , $t_{0}=t_{n}$ and define the map $S: \mathbb{T}_1 \to \mathbb{T}_1$ by the formula
\begin{align}
S(t)= t+c_j \quad \text{mod} \, 1 , \quad t \in [t_j,t_{j+1})
\end{align}
Here, the $c_j$ are real values. Each interval has its own $c_j$. They could be either the same or different from each other. Such map is called interval translation map (ITM) or, if it is one-to-one it is called interval exchange map (IEM).

It is easy to construct an example of an Interval Exchange Map, for example, the rotation map is a good example of that, but I think it is kind of hard to construct an example of an ITM which is *not* an IEM. Could anyone help me find a simple example?

Comment: How are the values $c_j$ connected to $t_j$? Are you adding a different constant $c_j$ to every interval?

Comment: @almosteverywhere Each interval has its own $c_j$. They could be either the same or different from each other

Comment: If possible,  you should clarify your question to indicate that. As it stands it may be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $n=1$ and write $\mathbb T^1 \simeq [0,1) = [0,1/2) \cup [1/2,1) $. Then, define
\begin{align}
S(t)=
\begin{cases}
t + 1/4 & t \in [0,1/2) \\
t-1/4 & t \in [1/2,1)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Unless I misunderstood your definitions, this seems to work.